# php: PDO exception handling

Tags: php, pdo, exception

I have two PHP files DBConnector.php

```
<?php

    class DBConnector {

        const DB_STRING = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
        const DB_USER = 'test';
        const DB_PASSWORD = 'qwerty';

        private $connection;

        function __construct() {
            $this->connection = new PDO(self::DB_STRING, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        function register_user($user_type, $login, $password, $email, $phone) {
            $insert_user_sql = "insert into users (login, password, email, rating, phones, user_type) 
                        values (:login, password(:password), :email, 0, :phone, :user_type)";

            $sth = $this->connection->prepare($insert_user_sql);

            $sth->execute(array(':login' => $login,
                                ':password' => $password,
                                ':email' => $email,
                                ':phone' => $phone,
                                ':user_type' => $user_type));

        }
    }
?>
```

and application.php

```
<?php

    require "DBConnector.php";
    require "UserType.php";

    try {
        $db = new DBConnector();
        $db->register_user(UserType::OWNER, "test", "test", "test@gmail.com", "+111111111111");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error occured " + $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

If the "insert into users" in DBConnector->register_user generates PDO exception, I can't catch it in my application.php. 
Please, help me, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I am not able to understand this `password(:password)`

Comment: @Saty PASSWORD is a MySQL hashing function.

Comment: @WayneWhitty thanks for updating my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The problem was in "plus" symbol, besides "." in echo command.
So "0" was printed, instead "Error occured..."